# Rails finding an active record using OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to find a record by doing something like this

@something = Model.where(X=1 OR Y=1)

But all the things I try don't work. This should be easy but I can't find the solution anywhere.

EDIT: To be more specific I am trying to find all records where X is 1 and Y is 1.

Comment: `X=1 OR Y=1` is not a particularly meaningful statement. What exactly are you trying to do? Use Y if X is nil else use X?

Comment: I want every record where X=1 and Y=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which set here do you want:

```
| id | x | y |
|  1 | 1 | 0 |
|  2 | 0 | 1 |
|  3 | 1 | 1 |
```

If you want 3 only: `Model.where(:x => 1, :y => 1)`

If you want 1, 2, and 3:

`tab=Model.arel_table; Model.where(tab[:x].eq(1).or(tab[:y].eq(1)))`

Or even: `Model.where(["x=? OR y=?",1,1])` if your OR statements aren't complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely want to use a where clause here on your model, i.e.

```
@something = Model.where('X=1 OR Y=1')
```

The stuff inside of the quotes is just SQL, so this would generate SQL that would look something like:

```
SELECT `model`.* FROM `model_table` WHERE (X = 1 or y = 1)
```

hope that helps!

ian.

Answer (score 2):

You may also benefit greatly from viewing the [Advanced Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) Railscast by Ryan Bates.